# How to extract first character and numbers after that until find a character (a-z) in a string - C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, c#-2.0

How to extract numbers from a second index of a string until find a character (a-z) in a string?

I am using C# version 2.0 (can't upgrade for some reasons).

Here are some examples;

- M000067TGFD45F   = M000067
- B000064TFR765TXT = B000064
- B000065TFR765    = B000065
- B000067TGFD      = B000067

I have tried Regex("[^0-9]") which works if there is no character after digits (4th example)

```
 "B" + regexOnlyNumbers.Replace(mystring, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Try this regex: `\b\D*\d+`

Comment: Or perhaps `\bB\d+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
string text = "M000067TGFD45F";
Match m = Regex.Match(text, @"^[A-Z][0-9]+");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Z%5D%5B0-9%5D%2B&i=M000067TGFD45F%20%3D%20M000067%0D%0AB000064TFR765TXT%20%3D%20B000064%0D%0AB000065TFR765%20%3D%20B000065%0D%0AB000067TGFD%20%3D%20B000067&o=m).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[0-9]+` - one or more ASCII digits.

Alternatively, you might consider a `^[A-Z][^A-Z]+` pattern, where `[^A-Z]+` matches any one or more chars other than uppercase ASCII letters.

To ignore case, use [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_IgnoreCase): `Regex.Match(text, @"^[A-Z][0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`.